# RenderTargetBitmap in Windows Phone 7 SDK

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7

`RenderTargetBitmap` is not present in Windows Phone 7 SDK, right ?

How can i take a screenshot of an UIElement instead?

**thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution by myself.

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(200,200); 
wb.Render(ui, new TranslateTransform());
wb.Invalidate();
```