# WP7 - Bing Maps - Convert map to png

Tags: windows-phone-7, png, bing-maps

I have the following questions:

There is an API for Bing Maps in WP7.

The question is there anything generating images from a data map. Something like a MapTiler. Too bad the MapTiler is for web. But I believe that is the same concept.

Given a map, returning the same in image format.

So, what do you say? Do you know any library that does this in WP7?

Comment: Are you wanting something to create map tiles out of an image? and then use the generated map tiles on the WP7? I don't quite understand what you want to do...

Comment: I want something to create images from map tiles!!

Comment: Create a map at runtime of the application, and show part of this map in a tile corresponding to the application, you know?

Comment: Okay, i was confused because you had mentioned MapTiler, which converts images to map tiles. However, to my understanding, this is not what you want to do. You want to do the opposite.

Comment: The easiest approach is to programmatically take a "Screen Shot" of the map control.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266715/rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-phone-7-sdk

Comment: I have to agree with @Bryan-Watts - it's very unclear what you're trying to do... Bing Maps tiles *are* images - 256px x 256px PNG/JPGs, to be precise, so saying you want to create an image from these images doesn't really make sense - are you trying to join Bing Maps tiles together into a larger image? Or, are you simply looking for an application that creates tiles from a georeferenced image - i.e. does the same functionality as can be found at www.MapTiler.org, but that runs on a WP7 handset. If so, why would you want to do this on a mobile device??!

Comment: I just want to show a portion of the map on a WP tile. Got it?

Comment: In that case, you're very confused as to what MapTiler does!

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet is probably to load the map on screen and take a screen shot of it
[RenderTargetBitmap in Windows Phone 7 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266715/rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-phone-7-sdk)